# Separate Month and year from a date array in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm having a array of dates in this dd MMM yyyy format.Now I need to separate month and year in separate arrays from this array. Now if I select particular month and year say if I bind the year and month arrays in UIpickerview  and select a particular year and month I need to get the corresponding list of dates in that year and month which was the dates in previous original array. For eg if Jan and 2012 are selected I need to get dates like {01 Jan 2012,05 Jan 2012,..28 Jan 2012} . I'm a beginner in objective C any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have date data, use a date *type*. There's little point dealing with strings when what you want to be dealing with is actual *dates*.

Answer (score 3):

First convert your string to NSDate by using NSDateFormatter, then using comparator extract day,month and year from the date, change the date format to your required format.

Check the following.

```
 NSString *date = @"10/12/2012";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
NSCalendar *calendar =[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:dateFromString];
int day =[components day]; //day from the date
int month = [components month];//month from the date
int year = [components year];// year from the date
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"] ;
NSString *InDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];//req format 10 jan 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly fulfilling your requirement but you can work around it.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components =
                    [gregorian components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | 
                                           NSYesrCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year  = [components year];
```

Comment: Thanks that will be really helpful I hope